# How can I have dmg files automatically unmount when I trash them?

Tags: automation, dmg, eject

A while ago, I used to have some kind of App or service that would automatically unmount a dmg file whenever I put the dmg file into the trash. This was really convenient, but I've since reinstalled OS X, and I've completely forgotten the name of the app that provides this useful feature. I still have backups of my old system, but I have no idea where to look. So, does anyone know of an app that provides this feature?

(Note: There are plentiful tutorials on how to achieve the reverse, i.e. auto-trash on eject, but this is not what I'm looking for.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two options

- Use a folder action on `~/.Trash` to unmount any DMG getting moved into the trash can (see second part of [this article](http://www.guidingtech.com/26874/eject-delete-dmg-files-automatically/), summarized below)
- [DMG Cleaner](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/50891/dmg-cleaner) claims to be able to do this as well

---

**Folder Action to unmount DMG moved to Trash**

1. Create a new "Folder Action" workflow in Automator
2. Set Folder Action to work on `~/.Trash`
3. Add a "Run Shell Script" action to the workflow
4. Set shell to "/usr/bin/python" and make sure input gets passed as arguments
5. Replace the content of the script box with the following script

   ```
   import string, os, sys
   lines = os.popen("hdiutil info").readlines()
   should_eject = False
   for line in lines:
       if line.startswith("image-alias"):
           path = line.split(":")[1]
           image_path = path.lstrip().rstrip()
           if image_path in sys.argv:
               should_eject = True
       elif line.startswith("/dev/") and should_eject is True:
           os.popen("hdiutil eject %s" % line.split()[0])
           should_eject = False
       elif line.startswith("###"):
           should_eject = False
   ```
6. Save the workflow

Comment: Thanks, I think this folder action was probably the solution I was using before!

Comment: I can confirm this still works on macOS Sierra 10.12.2. Thank you so much! This is a must-have workflow for me.